# ¿A qué se "agarra" un "agarrado"? ¿Al bolsillo?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos

Dice la RAE que **agarrado** es sinónimo de **tacaño**:

> **[agarrado, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=13gzer1)**
>
> Del part. de agarrar.
>
> 1. adj. coloq. tacaño (‖ que escatima en el gasto).

Y en efecto, lo usamos mucho. Sin embargo, estaba intentando imaginar el origen de la palabra y me surgió la duda: ¿a qué se considera que se agarra un agarrado? ¿al bolsillo? ¿a su riqueza? ¿Acaso quiere decir que alguien agarra algo y no lo suelta?

Comment: Se me imagina algo así como *asegurado*, algo en el sentido de ser *acaudalado* pero en realidad alguien que solo piensa en sus propios gastos.

Comment: Curioso, no había escuchado la expresión _agarrado_ para referirse a alguien tacaño, pero sí he escuchado: [amarrado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2FhPrOL)
Ejemplo: `Ese tipo si que es bien amarrado, ¿no?`

Comment: @Mauricio Parecida la que se usa bastante en mi país: *amarrete.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo estoy de acuerdo con tu sugerencia de `quiere decir que alguien agarra algo y no lo suelta`, y que ese algo es el dinero.

Algunos "sinónimos" o expresiones similares que he oído para expresar lo mismo serían por ejemplo "ser del puño cerrado" (o incluso ["ser de la cofradía del puño cerrado](http://expresionesyrefranes.com/2007/07/05/ser-de-la-cofradia-del-puno-o-ser-de-la-virgen-del-puno/)"), por ejemplo:

> No vas a conseguir que el del tercero acepte gastar un poco más en la reforma del ascensor. Ese es del **puño cerrado**

Y la expresión refiere a lo mismo: tener el puño cerrado agarrando el dinero sin soltarlo, sin ceder o darle algo a los demás.